# How to add column to my query using another query?

Tags: mysql

This is my current query.

```
SELECT com.commisionAmount, stu.studentName, pay.paymentDate, pay.paymentAmount
FROM `commisions` as com INNER JOIN `accounts` as acc ON com.commisionAccount = acc.id 
INNER JOIN `studentpayments` as pay ON com.paymentID = pay.id 
INNER JOIN `students` as stu ON pay.paymentStudent = stu.id 
WHERE pay.paymentDate BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' AND acc.id = '$id'
```

I want to also select stu.signedUpBy when doing this query...it's an ID that references acc.id but I want it to show acc.username that is attached to that ID. How would I best do that? I tried it as an inner join and it isn't working. Wrong results

```
SELECT com.commisionAmount, stu.studentName, pay.paymentDate, pay.paymentAmount, acco.username
FROM  `commisions` AS com
INNER JOIN  `accounts` AS acc ON com.commisionAccount = acc.id
INNER JOIN  `studentpayments` AS pay ON com.paymentID = pay.id
INNER JOIN  `students` AS stu ON pay.paymentStudent = stu.id
INNER JOIN `accounts` AS acco ON stu.signedUpBy = acc.id
WHERE pay.paymentDate
BETWEEN  '2016-08-01'
AND  '2016-10-31'
AND acc.id =  '46'
```

Comment: What's the problem? Why not just add the field in the SELECT? What's the UNION for?

Comment: I don't know how to make it show the username rather than the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to add another `JOIN` to accounts.  You can then pull in the user name:

```
SELECT c.commisionAmount, s.studentName, p.paymentDate, p.paymentAmount,
       a2.username
FROM commisions c INNER JOIN
     accounts a
     ON c.commisionAccount = a.id INNER JOIN
     studentpayments sp
     ON c.paymentID = sp.id INNER JOIN
     students s
     ON p.paymentStudent = s.id LEFT JOIN
     accounts a2
     ON a2.id = s.signedupby
WHERE p.paymentDate BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' AND
      a.id = '$id';
```

Comment: Just as you commented I changed my inner join to left and it worked. Which is your solution. Thank you kindly sir!